# C# How to correct wrong input within an array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, input

So I need to do a array loop with students for class. The input has to be between 0-100 otherwise it doesn't accept the input from the user.

```
  Console.WriteLine("How many students?");
  int num1 = Keyboard.ReadInt();
  int[] array = new int[num1];
  Console.WriteLine("Give the student grades: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
  {
      int wrong;
      wrong = Keyboard.ReadInt();
      if (wrong > 0 && wrong <= 100)
      {
          array[i] = wrong;
      }
      else
      {
          while (wrong < 0 && wrong >= 100)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Wrong input:");
              wrong = Keyboard.ReadInt();
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you just need to change [`&&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to [`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
while (wrong < 0 || wrong >= 100) ...
```

A number cannot be lower than zero **and** greater than 99 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `wrong` variable can't be less then `0` and and bigger than `100` at the same time.

You should say: *if wrong is less than `0` **OR** bigger than `100`*

That's why you need to use [`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`&&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this :

```
while (wrong < 0 || wrong >= 100)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Wrong input:");
     wrong = Keyboard.ReadInt();
}
```

or you could change `while` to `if` here:

```
if (wrong < 0 || wrong >= 100)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Wrong input:");
     wrong = Keyboard.ReadInt();
}
```

or you could remove the whole block and use it in `else` statement in these two ways:

```
if (wrong > 0 && wrong <= 100)
{
    array[i] = wrong;
}
else if(wrong < 0 || wrong >= 100)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Wrong input:");
     wrong = Keyboard.ReadInt();
}
```

or

```
if (wrong > 0 && wrong <= 100)
{
    array[i] = wrong;
}
else 
{
     Console.WriteLine("Wrong input:");
     wrong = Keyboard.ReadInt();
}
```

Comment: Seemed to work. The teacher did it the some other way around and I got confused. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, besides instead of `while` you can just use `if` here. I'm gonna try to edit my answer to explain better